# Why does the TFS build run serially on build agents? Why not parallel builds?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Why does the TFS run only one build at a time on the build agents? Why cant it spin up another process and kick off another build on the same build agent?

Forgive me if I am missing something too obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build (and test) Agent are designed to do sequential builds.

If you need parallel builds on a machine, just add more agents.

I currently have 24 agents on a single machine capable of running 24 builds in parallel.

Comment: @AG_85 It gives you control over the degree of parallelism. You can select how many, when to enable them, where the source for each is stored. They could have created a build "server" product, that has a config for all these things, but not called them agents. :)

Comment: About agents: "Make sure the build server that hosts your build agents has sufficient storage and processing capabilities to match the size and complexity of the codebase and tests on the team project collection. Typically, you should host no more than one build agent per processor core on the build server. You can also enhance performance by dedicating a single physical hard drive to the working directory of each build agent."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135.aspx